# (Rendimiento) Es mejor un solo archivo query o crear uno para cada consulta

Tags: php

Amigos tengo una duda, de que forma de trabajar repercute mas en el rendimiento servidor, estoy creando una query en php. Pero mi duda es si creo solo un solo query y a cada categoría le asignó una variable para que ese mismo query diferencie cada consulta o creo un query para cada categoría. Varios usuarios estarían efectuando las consultas de forma aleatoria

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, faltan detalles sobre el contexto, además, las preguntas basadas en opiniones no se adaptan al formato del sitio. En contextos como el que describes, generalmente el usuario elige una categoría, la cual es recogida para agregarla como criterio en la consulta: `SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE categoria = laCategoriaSeleccionada`. Se suele hacer así. A partir de ahí, cualquier duda concreta que tengas, indícala en la pregunta explicando el contexto, poniendo el código que estás usando, los errores que estás teniendo, las pruebas que has hecho, etc.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta A. Cedano, este ejemplo cual de las 2 opciones es más recomendable con varios usuarios interactuando                                                                                   
Ejemplo 1. Categ1, Categ2   ( SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE categoria = Categ1)                                   
( SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE categoria = la Categ2)  Ejemplo 2.  $tabla='tabla' ;  $categoría = La Categoría Selec' ; $categT=categoriaTabla                                                         
 ( SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $categT=$categoria)

Comment: Sigo sin entender la duda. Parece que son dos consultas distintas, destinadas a fines distintos, por lo tanto, no se puede decir: este es mejor en cuanto a rendimiento, porque ambas deberían ser para fines diferentes. Sugiero que pulses en [edit]  y aclares un poco la pregunta a ver si logra entenderse tu duda.